# xlsx parser with objective-c

Tags: objective-c, xlsx

I found some parsing libraries but those are written by using python or perl. I tried to translate to objective-c but I could not do that because of my skills including objective-c.

https://github.com/staale/python-xlsx

https://github.com/typester/Data-XLSX-Parser

If you have any hints to make the parser, please share me. Thanks

### Fixed the issue

1. unzip .xlsx file.
2. parse xl/workbook.xml to get sheet's name.
3. parse xl/sharedStrings.xml to get strings.
4. parse xl/worksheets/sheetXXX.xml to get cells's postion and value.

I use "ZipArchive" but I got some warings such as deprecated error.

I use NSXMLParser but I do not know whether using the SAX parser is the best way or not. I use just three method to parse.

1. -(BOOL)parse;
2. -(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict
3. -(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string

Comment: I solved the problem. I made the parser from scratch.

Comment: @ yusaku could you please tell me the way to view/read a .xlsx file in objective c for ios. I will be very thankfull to you

Comment: @ yusaku could you please tell how did you do it. please share the code. Thankyou

Comment: @Pandey_Laxman Sorry, I'm late to realize your message. You can view a .xlsx by doing unzip the .xlsx file. I use ZipArchive but you can find another libraries you like.

Comment: @Vinod ram I am afraid I can not show whole of the code because of the terms and conditions with my client. But it is not difficult. First, unzip a .xlsx file. You can see some .xml files which include excel's sheets data. And then you can parse the XML. I use NSXMLParser but I do not know whether the SAX parser is suitable to your condition or not.

Comment: @yusaku thanks for takin time and replying.

Comment: @yusaku thanks for your time could you plz elaborate how to after unzipping what next I have to do to view .xlsx file.

Comment: @Pandey_Laxman I edited my question. Please take a look. If you use NSXMLParser, you might have to have some flags like foundCharactersFlag and etc. If you have any questions, I will try to answer as much as possible.

Comment: @yusaku Thanks a lot for your time and have been very helpful for the above topic. But how to zip .xlsx file and unzip it , I mean which method, what code you apply to make unzip. I used to nsxml parser Thanks.

Comment: @Pandey_Laxman You don't need to zip your .xlsx file. just unzip like this. ZipArchive* za = [[ZipArchive alloc] init];
if(!([za UnzipOpenFile:PATH_TO_XMLS_FILE] && [za UnzipFileTo:PATH_TO_UNZIP_DIR overWrite:YES])) {
  // error handling
}

Comment: @Pandey_Laxman You have .xlsx file you want to read, don't you?

Comment: @yusaku  Okay Thanks a lot , now I am all set :)